# Rails protect_from_forgery breaks login form if idle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

In our Rails application we use `protect_from_forgery` to prevent CSRF.

However what we found is that if a user visits the login page and then goes off to make a cup of tea for the duration of what the app session expiration time is (let's say 15 minutes). The login just redirects back to the login page regardless of successful credentials or not (Depending on the environment, we get the error `InvalidAuthenticityToken`.) Trying to login again works fine. It only fails if the user has been on the page for longer than the session time.

We thought this was weird because we haven't logged in yet... so what session is expiring? and surely a new session is being created on login even if one was created and had expired. Turns out (after reading this: https://nvisium.com/blog/2014/09/10/understanding-protectfromforgery/) the CSRF protection in Rails actually uses a session to check the `authenticity_token` is valid. So basically the token expires when the session expires (depending on `session_store` setting), and you can't login without refreshing the page again.

We solved this doing: `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:create]` in our `SessionsController` but now that means our login form is no longer protected.

What other options are there to fix this? Or is the solution we have used not as insecure as we think? Googling shows this line of code used lots of times, but surely it's a bad idea?

Our other solution was to allow the Exception to happen, but handle it gracefully with:

```
rescue_from ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken do
  @exception = exception.message
  render 'errors/500', :status => 500, :layout => 'other'
end
```

Though still hating the fact a user sitting on the login page for longer than the session timeout (in this case 15 mins) causes an error!

---

Yet another solution we have come up with is to set the session_store to forever and then manually expire login sessions like this:

```
before_action :session_timeout, if: :current_user

def session_timeout
  session[:last_seen_at] ||= Time.now
  if session[:last_seen_at] < 15.minutes.ago
    reset_session
  else
    session[:last_seen_at] = Time.now
  end
end
```

Comment: What kind of `session_store` do you use.?

Answer (score 10):

> so what session is expiring?

The session in question is the Rails Session (see [What are Sessions?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) in the [Ruby on Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html)), which is a lightweight data-storage abstraction that persists arbitrary state across HTTP requests (in an encrypted cookie by default, other session-storage implementations can also be configured). Session state *may* include an authenticated user ID, but it can also be used for other purposes.

In this case, the session is not being used for user authentication, but to store a temporary 'authenticity token' as part of a Rails security feature that protects your website against [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) (CSRF) attacks on POST (or other non-GET) requests.

The [Rails API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html) describes this feature in more detail:

> Controller actions are protected from Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks by including a token in the rendered HTML for your application. This token is stored as a random string in the session, to which an attacker does not have access. When a request reaches your application, Rails verifies the received token with the token in the session.

See also the [Cross-Site Request Forgery](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf) section of the [Ruby on Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) for a more complete overview of what a CSRF attack is, and how session-based authenticity-token verification protects against it.

> What other options are there to fix this?

- Increase the duration of your Rails session expiration time (e.g., by increasing the duration of the `expire_after` option passed to your `cookie_store` initializer, or removing the option entirely to make the session never expire).
- Instead of using session-cookie expiration to expire logged-in sessions, use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)'s `:timeoutable` module:

  ```
  devise :timeoutable, timeout_in: 15.minutes
  ```

> Or is the solution we have used not as insecure as we think?

Configuring Rails to skip the `verify_authenticity_token` callback disables CSRF protection for that particular controller action, which makes the action vulnerable to CSRF attacks.

So to rephrase your question, is disabling CSRF protection ***only*** for the `SessionsController#create` action still ***insecure*** in any significant/meaningful sense? Though this depends on your application, in general **yes**, I believe so.

Consider this scenario:

A CSRF attack against `SessionsController#create` would allow an attacker to maliciously direct a victim's browser to login to a user account under the attacker's control. The next time the victim visited your website (e.g., when redirected by the attacker), their browser could still be logged in to the attacker-controlled account. The victim could then unknowingly submit sensitive personal data or perform sensitive actions on your website that could be read by the attacker.

While this scenario may be less obviously dangerous than what could happen if CSRF protection were disabled on other more sensitive/destructive controller actions, it still exposes enough of a potential user/data-privacy issue that I consider it to be insecure enough to recommend *against* disabling the default protection.

Comment: Great response, thanks! Seems like it's a bit of a compromise... either disable the token and open yourself up for CSRF attack or extend/disable the expire of the session but then open yourself up to other security issues.

Comment: One solution we had was to manually destroy sessions for auth but allow other sessions to last indefinitely. See updated post.

Comment: @Cameron if you extend the session-cookie expiry, you should be able to use Devise's `timeoutable` module to expire logged-in sessions without any additional code: `devise :timeoutable, timeout_in: 15.minutes`.

Comment: I am using timeoutable but I am still facing a similar issue. If the browser window is left open for too long, the current_session times out, but eventually the authenticity_token times out too, and when that happens, attempting to log in throws a CSRF error.

Comment: @wjordan I have a doubt about your response but I thought it was better to create a new post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75026529/protect-from-forgery-and-login-forms, could you post your thoughts, please?

Answer (score 3):

```
InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

This error comes when "authenticity token" created while rendering form (login form) is already expired.

There are only two ways by which we can resolve this issue.

- Configuring Rails to skip the **verify_authenticity_token** for controller#action  - Insecure as already mentioned in the question
- (Only left way)Auto reload the screen(here Login screen ) whenever such exception encountered.

Find the modified code for the same and add this in **application_controller.rb** to generalize the solution for whole application.

```
rescue_from ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken do
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to include some JS on the page that would automatically reload a little while before your token expires (and therefore keep the auth token valid).

You would probably want to check to check for mouse/keyboard action before reloading in case the user is just in the process of filling out the form.

It seems that the biggest downside of this option would be the fact that the JS is decoupled from the actual amount of time the auth token is valid... So it could prove to be a maintenance issue if you change your timeout duration often.