# Handling CSRF Errors in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, csrf

I've got a scenario where a user may lay idle on a page and after about 15 minutes a post request from a user's browser will trigger a invalid CSRF token error. This question has been somewhat helpful, but I'm still uncertain how I should handle the error.

[Rails protect_from_forgery breaks login form if idle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557350/rails-protect-from-forgery-breaks-login-form-if-idle/41786452)

One comment in the question I have linked to above noted security issues with extending the Rails cookie expiration time. Is this indeed the case? Should I instead refresh the page when this error is thrown? I do not want to disable the CSRF protection. What would be the best way to handle this error and maintain usability? I'm also using Devise in my application.

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

Comment: It seems like the question you're asking is an exact duplicate of the question you linked to, and your questions are already discussed and answered there. Can you explain why you asked another question, and why the existing answers to the duplicate question aren't working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you linked already provide some insights of what you could do Server Side.

You can however prevent stale forms submission client side. Some javascript / UI tweaks can help you.

Here are some ideas : 
 - Display a Countdown
 - Pop up after 15 minutes that tells u to refresh
etc.

Someone can always open the code and submit but then you dont care about that 422 error in the face of people trying to hack around.