# protect_from_forgery and login forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, session, csrf, authenticity-token

Reading about how `protect_from_forgery` works, I came across multiple articles such as [this one](https://blog.nvisium.com/understanding-protectfromforgery) which explains that the `authenticity_token` is bound to the user's session. All clear so far. But a question came up, how does `protect_from_forgery` work with login forms since it's supposed there isn't a user's session yet? I'd think `protect_from_forgery` could be disabled for the `sessions#create` action but the scenario that [@wjordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2518355/wjordan) proposes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41786452/4801466) makes sense to me, but I can't figure out how it works.

Comment: I think you are confusing a browser session with apps that create user_sessions to allow a user to be authenticated. The browser session just ensures that the web server is talking to the same browser, but it doesn't have any concept of an internal user yet. A rails app that creates a user_session has to have the authentication mechanism ignored for the initial form.

Comment: The point being that using the authenticity_token the server knows that the request came from the same computer browser session that initiated the session to prevent cross site scripting hacks.

Comment: I don't think so, since Rails guides talk about user sessions, not browser sessions: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf. It makes sense as a CSRF attack is performed when the victim opens a malicious link in the same browser where the victim session is active. So, if what you say was right, whatever request by the victim from the malicious origin at the same browser will be allowed by the app server. Let me know if I'm still worng. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the OWASP's definition which describes the CSRF as an attack aimed at authenticated users: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users visiting a website do have a session before logging in however it is an unauthenticated session (also referred to as a pre-session). The CSRF is bound to that session. If you are using Devise, once you log in you will get another session. A good explainer on the types of attacks this mitigates is provided here https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#login-csrf The linked paper within the article has detailed examples which are great!